# Using ASP.NET DI for SignalR with TinyIoC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

In a project, I'm using Nancy/TinyIoC for Dependency Injection. I had no problems thus far.

I added SignalR to my project and setup my hubs so that I'm injecting `IHubContext` into my hub.

I'm running into a problem that when TinyIoC tries to resolve one of its dependency trees, it runs into an ASP.NET type and cannot resolve such. How do I work around this? My first guess was to register the type within TinyIoC, but that seems tedious.

Here's what I have:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            // Register types from ASP.net
            // Pass instances to UseNancy
            var hubContext = builder.ApplicationServices.GetService<IHubContext<MessageSender>>();

            builder
                .UseCors(AllowAllOrigins)
                .UseSignalR(HubRegistration.RouteRegistrations)
                .UseOwin(x => x.UseNancy());
        }

        public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(AllowAllOrigins,
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder
                            .AllowAnyOrigin()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowCredentials();
                    });
            });

            services.AddSignalR();
        }
    }

    public class MessageRepo : IRepository<Message>
    {
        private readonly IDatabase<Message> _database;
        private readonly IValidator<Message> _messageValidator;
        private readonly IMessageSender<Message> _hubContext;

        public MessageRepo(IDatabase<Message> database, IValidator<Message> messageValidator, IMessageSender<Message> hubContext)
        {
            _database = database;
            _messageValidator = messageValidator;
            _hubContext = hubContext;
        }
    }

    public class MessageSender : Hub, IMessageSender<Message>
    {
        public MessageSender(IHubContext<MessageSender> context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If TinyIOC is activating your class it needs to know about those dependencies, there's no way around that.